# Visual Studio Code colours not the same as Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have started using VS Code but there seems to be an annoying difference in basic code text colours. An example if the below code. In Visual Studio 2019...

[image: Visual Studio 2019 example]

However in VS Code it shows as...

[image]

Where the second Process is white not green. There are other types that I have coloured white in the settings.json file so I don't want them to be different. Is there any way to single out a give word or type rather than having to apply colours to say variable.other.object in the settings file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried downloading other themes?  (this is not really a SO question)

Comment: I have and they all show the same difference.

Comment: @alex in that case you can customize the theme file to match what you want. Essentially, you're asking how to customize a theme, or whether there's a theme that matches some other theme

Comment: Maybe a better example is where say I want to colour certain types green and certain types white (which they are by default in VS 2019). But in VS-code both those types are the same i.e. variable.other.object. So how can they be set differently in vs-code?